# httpbuilder and apache.poi.workbook maven problems

Tags: maven, groovy, httpbuilder

In Maven POM file I have the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
    <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>stax</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to use `Httpbuilder` and `Workbook` in my project to parse Excel files.

```
def res = http.post("path": "....", "requestContentType": JSON, contentType: ContentType.BINARY)

Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(res.responseData)
```

Errors:

1. If I use my Maven dependencies

---

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable 
initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl
```

2. If I add exclusion to stax or to httpbuilder

---

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
```

3. If I delete stax dependency

---

```
javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found
```

Any ideas on how to use `HttpBuilder` with `Workbook`?

Answer (score 0):

Exclude xerces from http-builder dependencies. In my case it solved problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
    <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```